# JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start

Tags: java, json

The Json String

```
String field="[{"
        + "{\"key\":\"cloud\",\"value\":[\"AWS\"],\"search\":\"EQUALITY\"}"
        + ",{\"key\":\"region\",\"value\":[\"US EAST1\"],\"search\":\"EQUALITY\"}"
        + "}]";
```

Code causing error:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.readValue(field, ComputeResourceInputVO[].class)
```

related class

```
public class ComputeResourceInputVO implements Serializable {
    public ComputeResourceInputField[] computeResourceInputField;
}

class ComputeResourceInputField implements Serializable {

    public String[] value;
    public String search;
    public String key;
}
```

**Error:**

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

Comment: That is not valid JSON, so I recommend you **learn JSON**. Once you think you've fixed the JSON, **validate your JSON** to make sure, e.g. using an online validator like https://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra open curly bracket:

```
String field="[{" // 1st open curly
// second line starts with another curly
    + "{\"key\":\"cloud\",\"value\":[\"AWS\"],\"search\":\"EQUALITY\"}"
    + ...
```

Change the first line to:

```
String field="[" // extra open curly  removed
```

And remove the last closing curly in your json.

Comment: I want to construct an Array of `ComputeResourceInputVO`. Where `ComputeResourceInputVO` will have an array of  `ComputeResourceInputField` in it. Can you please correct my Json please

Comment: the First [] i added for array, and the First {} is for `ComputeResourceInputVO` and the second curly brackets i added for the `ComputeResourceInputField`.

Comment: @upog no. The `[]` define an array. Inside the array should be `{"key":"foo", ...}` for each object’s fields. Try doing what I have suggested in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the line --> mapper.readValue(field, ComputeResourceInputVO[].class)
This means that fields which is a json needs to be mapped to an **array of ComputeResourceInputVO**

Next:

Inside the class **ComputeResourceInputVO** you have an **array of ComputeResourceInputField**

Inside **ComputeResourceInputField** you have the attribute defined.

So with this type of code, the field json String is malformed.

you should have something like this

```
[{"computeResourceInputField":[{"value":["String1","String2"],"search":"USEAST","key":"A"},{"value":["String3","String4"],"search":"USWEST","key":"B"}]}]
```